# how to create world frame!

Tags: kinect, octomap, frames, husky, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I've worked on simulated husky with simulated kinect to create a customize 3d occupancy map, i want to transform the pointcloud frame to map or world frame, but i don't have these frames, just i can translate to odom frame, for creating 3d occupancy map, is it enough or i should add a link in my urdf or any thing else to create world frame ?!
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94731/how-to-create-world-frame!!!/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) on 2017-10-06**:
How could you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way would be to use static_transform_publisher to add a link between your Kinect frame and the simulated Husky base_link. That represents the physical link between the Husky and the sensor.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1